# "No visible @inteface ... declares ..." error for properties

Tags: objective-c

Why would the following:

`[object propertyName:propertyValue]` cause the above exception in Xcode 4.3 and Lion, but `object.propertyName=propertyValue` would work just fine?
The @property in question is a simple float and I've also used @synthesize.

I'm relatively new to Objective C, but have quite a bit of experience in C#,  and have been reading Aaron Hillegass' book on the topic where the two approaches are listed as synonymous, with the [...] being the preferred one.

Answer (score 3):

The setter method is not named the same as the property.  You want `setPropertyName` instead of `propertyName` when calling it as a method.  The getter is still just the property name.

See [How to write my own setter for an ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4150987/901059) for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@property` and `@syntesize` to declare variable, system write get and set methods for you. And on this you need use `[object setPropertyName:propertyValue]`. Also you can use `object.propertyName=propertyValue` but it's a C programming style.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using the property without the "set" prefix was indeed causing the problem.