# Properties and accessors in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, accessor

Does the following code call an accessor "set" function or does it modify the pointer `myMember` directly?

aClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSArray *myMember;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myMember;
```

aClass.c

```
@implementation GameplayScene

@synthesize myMember;

- (id) init {
    if ( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        myMember = [NSArray array];
    }
}
```

In other words, I would like to know if the method `setMyMember` is being called, or if the pointer of `myMember` is being modified directly.

Likewise, is `myMember = [NSArray array]` identical to `self.myMember = [NSArray array]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between self.ivar and ivar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142177/difference-between-self-ivar-and-ivar) and a [whole lot more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+property+ivar).

Comment: Thanks @Josh Caswell.  I did look around, but I guess not far enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the `self.` notation, the instance variable is modified directly. With it, the property setter is called (and since you made it a `retain` property, the new pointer that it's being set to will be sent a `retain` message).

See Apple's documentation on [declaring](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) and [accessing properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17).