# Do I use _property or self.property in implementation

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between self.ivar and ivar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142177/difference-between-self-ivar-and-ivar)

Let's say I have the following class

```
@interface
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) MyObject* property;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize property = _property;

-(id) init{
   if ((self = [super init])) {
        _property = [MyObject new];
        self.property = [MyObject new];
        NSLog(@"%@", _property.description);
        NSLog(@"%@", self.property.description);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

What is the correct way? using accessors (synthesize: self.property) or using the ivar directly? It's just that i have sometimes felt that using the accessors caused in errors when I try to use them in other files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either is fine.  Using `self.property` calls the getter or setter method (either synthesized or defined), while `_property` accesses the instance variable directly.

Since `self.property` calls a method, it can have side effects.  For example:

```
- (Property *)property {
    if (_property == nil) {
        _property = [[Property alloc] init];
    }
    return _property;
}
```

Calling `self.property` will create the a new Property and assign it to `_property` if it does not exist before returning that value, whereas `_property` will point to nil if it is accessed before `self.property` has been called for the first time on a particular instance of this class.

In fact, `@property` declarations do not have to correspond to instance variables; an implementation of the `-property` method could create and return a new Property each time it is invoked.