# How to use properties in Obj C

Tags: objective-c

I was trying to learn how to use properties in iOS programming.
I just want to check with people here if what I got is right?

Say I have a property

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;

@end
```

in implementation

```
@implementation XYZPerson
@synthesize firstName;
...
@end
```

By this,

a) an *instance variable* named: `firstName` is created

b) *whenever* I want to use property inside my class, I call `self.firstName` (or setter/getter)

c) I can initialize the property in the init method like this:

```
-(id) init {
 ...
 self.firstName=@"SomeText";
 ... 
 }
```

I believe the points I mentioned above, are correct, right?

Comment: Yes, correct!! For more, refer Apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Comment: One more thing, remember the use of @ in init method for `NSString`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I use \_property or self.property in implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791851/do-i-use-property-or-self-property-in-implementation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you say is pretty much correct although you are missing a few things from your `@property` declaration. You need at the very least a property attribute like `strong` or `copy` or `assign`. For strings which might be mutable, we generally use `copy` to ensure the string can't be modified from under us. So `@property (copy) NSString *firstName`. [See this answer for more details about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain).

Most people use `nonatomic` as well to improve performance by disabling thread synchronization in the generated getters/setters. [See this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties).

Some people recommend against using property accessors  in the `init` method (preferring direct ivar access) because subclasses might have overridden the setter/getter and might not work correctly until the object is fully initialized. Practically speaking you very rarely need to worry about this so a lot of people ignore this advice.

With the latest version of Xcode you also don't have to add the `@synthesize` manually - an underscore-prefixed instance variable (`_firstName` in your example) will be synthesized for you automatically.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks. I just like above approach so if it is ok I think I will use it mostly (I understand your comments about copy etc.). Final things. If I have just a instance variable (no property) -- I don't need to use `self` before it when referring to it right? (Whereas with properties, I must always use `self.propertyName?`)

Comment: If you only have an instance variable, you can't use the dot-property syntax at all.

Comment: @Mike: Which means I must refer to it directly. e.g., ivarName

Comment: @Mike: How one should decide whether to use instance variables or properties? I think one can always use properties right.

Comment: It's an age-old question: instance var or getter? I would go with using the property syntax unless you have critical performance concerns or some other good reason.

Comment: @Mike: by getter you mean a property?