# When getter function of a property is called in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I define a property for a class in its implementation file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
```

Then I override its getter function by `-(UIView*)headerView(){...}` to obtain some resources from main bundle.

In following code I need to set the property 'headerView' as subview to other views after it loads resource. Here are code fails to load resource.

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:_headerView];
```

Getter function is not invoked. I change property variable to self.headerView:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
```

It works now...

is there any difference between self.xxx and _xxx ? I think them identical to a property as different facets.

Comment: [Difference between _ and self. in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333495/difference-between-and-self-in-objective-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_property and self.property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889216/difference-between-property-and-self-property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties are backed by instance variables in Objective-C. Essentially, `@property` generates a getter and setter method by default that you access via `self.property`. If you use `_property`, you're bypassing the setter and getters and jumping straight to the instance variable. The only time you should use instance variables directly consist of in the `init`/`dealloc` or when you need to bypass a side effect someone may have implemented in a getter/setter method. Otherwise you should always use `self.property` rather `_property` to access and set your variables.